# How to hide database password in config file

Tags: c++, database, passwords, configuration-files

I am working on a C++ project that needs to access database for reading its input.

So far, we used a default username(postgres) and a 'fixed clear text' password stored , along with many other settings, in a xml based configuration file.

*Now what I need is to hide password from users when I supply the configuration file.*

*FYI: the development area is linux, database is postgresql. we would like to give users the config file to connect to database and use it without knowing the password*

I will appreciate if you suggest a quick and easy reference.(a small reading material will also be great)

thank you

Comment: If the database is SQL Server, use Windows authentication so you do not need to store a password.

Comment: @brianbeuning the development area is linux, database is postgresql. we would like to give users the config file to connect to database and use it without knowing the password.

Comment: The only secure solution is to make a user type the password every time your program starts.  If you encrypt the password, then you need to hide the key in your program somewhere.  The key can be found, but the effort required to get the password goes up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot prevent a ill-intentioned user from obtaining this password one way or another if you ship him the program containing it in any form.

But there are two potential solutions:

1. The user and password that ship with the program have a read-only access to the database;
2. The program don't connect directly to the database. It requests the data to a server application that can not only fetch this data from the actual database without need to give the user any password, but also can do the proper security checks to ensure this user is accessing only data he is meant to etc.

Comment: First solution can still let the user view the database which is exactly what I dont want. Second solution looks nice but 'too' perfect for me. I need a much simpler solution that wont require a server etc.

Comment: Perhaps only give access to some tables? That will depend a lot on your specific problem. In any case you should consider the second solution, even if it delays your project by some days.

Comment: If you want a suggestion you can rapidly implement something like this using PHP. Your program do HTTP requests to a PHP script with the necessary parameters, and the PHP will return the requested data in XML or JSON format. Your program parse it and the trick is done.

Answer (score 4):

You can have another "hardcoded" password, used to encrypt the password in the config file. So  you write the encrypted database password (db_password) to the config file, and then, when you need to access a database, you decrypt the db_password with your hardcoded password.
Of course, it is still possible to recover your password using decompiler for example, but it will not be easy.

Comment: Its actually easier than you think. A simple network debugging program like Wireshark can catch this password from the network traffic as the application connects to the database. You could use the most sophisticated encryption in the world to protect this password in the XML file and it wouldn't make any difference here.

Comment: @Havenard I have read your answer also. I am trying to figure out your second solution but it wont be easy and doable in 1-2 days, unless I am overestimating.

Comment: FreeNickname your solution is easy(though breakable). Still might be able to answer my requirement temporarily. I will give it a try but I need a reference for easy encryption/decryption in c++. can you help me with that?

Comment: @Havenard, if it is possible, you can use https to connect to the database. Of course, I'm agree that your solution is more correct. But it takes a lot of work to implement, so I decided to suggest another option.

Comment: @rahman, unfortunately I can't name you some exact library.But a "quick-and-easy" solution is to simply xor the DB password and the main password.

Answer (score -5):

We use MD5 to encipher the password in the config file.

Comment: MD5 is a one-way hash algorithm. Hashing the password would make it unreadable by everything *including* the application. And MD5 is generally considered a poor choice for anything security-related.