# How we can give encrypted password in JNDI in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jndi

Could you please tell me how we can provide encrypted password in the JNDI configuration and how we can decrypt that in the SPRING. In spring,

I see that we have to configure the datasource using

```
<bean id="DatabaseName" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/DatabaseName"/>
</bean>
```

but how we can override & decrypt the password in this, could you please help me

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Your problem really has little to do with Spring - it is more like "How do I hide the database password".
One of the best methods is to create a datasource manually from the J2EE console. Weblogic and IBM Websphere support this, and automatically obfusticate the password. Your program then asks the container for a database connection, and need not supply the password. (There is an assumption that if you have deployment rights to the server, then you can connect freely to the server's datasources).

Tomcat is a bit more problematical. The datasource will be specified in ../conf/context.xml, and the password will be in plaintext. You need to use Unix file permissions to keep out those who should not know the password.

This answer [How to hide database password in config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962527/how-to-hide-database-password-in-config-file) shows that this is a non-trivial problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But if suppose, I have given an encrypted password in the jboss configuration file, how I can connect it to the database from Spring as I have to decrypt it. Could you please give me an idea on this. thanks in advance

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. I think you need the JBoss secret key, and that aint likely to be public knowledge :) Can you not obtain the plaintext credentials from the database administrator and create a datasource as suggested?

Comment: Yes, I can't expose the password, so how in spring I can decrypt it if I use the jndi configuration as above, thanks